# python - unable to execute python script that uses pymongo

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

Total python noob here. Trying to learn python. I'm using macosx with high sierra `10.13.5` and have python `Python 2.7.10`.  My task here is to run a mongodb query using python, but to no avail as i'm trying to use `pymongo`.

Here's the message that I'm seeing: (executed on command line `python mydev.py`)

```
  File "mydev.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pymongo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 20, in <module>
    from bson.code import Code
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from bson.dbref import DBRef
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/dbref.py", line 17, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

I got this same message running the python shell with just `import pymongo` and running the script.

My python script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import pymongo
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

# DB connect
client = MongoClient('10.1.2.345')
db = client.test
collection = db.my_profiles

# Read
print collection.find_one({"account" : "foo", "profile" : "bar", "info.published" : True}, {"account":1, "profile":1,"settings.region":1})
```

So, i don't know how do i get this to work.  What pkgs am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you also need to add the port number

Comment: i got the same error messages just running the python shell and using `>>> import pymongo`

Comment: You have a messed up Python path and are importing modules from the wrong versions of Python.  Basically, this is you: https://xkcd.com/1987/    You need to determine which Python you're actually running and where it came from, and make sure you're running that and only that Python without any other entries on `sys.path`.  It has nothing really to do with pymongo.

Comment: oh boy, any docs on how to clean this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the hint that it was not `pymongo` but the fact that I have multiple versions of python running on my mac. It became clearer after more research that having multiple versions of python can be problematic.  I read this article - https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html#ide

I was able to successfully run the python script like so:

`/usr/bin/python mydev.py`